# ps axo : display full username based on PID number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to display full username by PID number

The first Approach i tried :

```
PID=12345
PID_USER=`ps -u -p ${PID}| awk '{print $1}' | tail -1`
echo $PID_USER
```

this will display as systemU+, i want to display as SystemUser_Farid

i have tried a second approach using ps axo ,  script used as

`ps axo user:20,pid`  , however , this is printing the whole list of processes , using `ps axo -p ${PID} user:20,pid` doesnt show any result.

Comment: `ps -o user= -p $PID` works fine here

Comment: I was searching for hours. Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-o format` for a user-defined format and only print the user name:

```
ps -o user= -p "$PID"
```

The `=` disables printing the header line.